# Zeppelin: misconfiguration

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I'm getting this error message when I'm trying to run my zeppelin:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
 WARN [2020-05-25 09:08:31,181] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:159) - Failed to load configuration, proceeding with a default
 INFO [2020-05-25 09:08:31,241] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:171) - Server Host: 0.0.0.0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "tcp://172.30.239.172:80"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.conf.ZeppelinConfiguration.getInt(ZeppelinConfiguration.java:248)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.conf.ZeppelinConfiguration.getInt(ZeppelinConfiguration.java:243)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.conf.ZeppelinConfiguration.getServerPort(ZeppelinConfiguration.java:327)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.conf.ZeppelinConfiguration.create(ZeppelinConfiguration.java:173)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.main(ZeppelinServer.java:129)
```

I'm deploying zeppelin without any configuration.

**EDIT:**

Additional error message after having set `ZEPPELIN_PORT`:

```
ERROR [2020-05-25 12:41:41,354] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:262) - Error while running jettyServer
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:220)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.main(ZeppelinServer.java:253)
```

Comment: what is the zeppelin version?

Comment: I'm using `apache/zeppelin:0.9.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using [links with Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/link-env-deprecated/), or something like, so it defines the `ZEPPELIN_PORT` environment variable for Zeppelin container that has a form of `tcp://172.30.239.172:80`. But this environment variable should contain only port, like, `80`, or `8080`.

To fix the problem try to rename linked container from `zeppelin` to something else, so it won't override the environment variable that is used by Zeppelin itself.

Comment: Thanks @Alex It was solved setting `ZEPPELIN_PORT` explicitly. However, I'm getting this other message (exposed on post). I'm trying to get `zeppelin` work on a kubernetes (openshift) cluster...

Comment: Zeppelin running as non-root user, so it can't use ports < 1024.  Do you follow instructions at https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/docs/quickstart/kubernetes.md ?

Comment: Hi @Alex again. Could you take a look on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62209713/zeppelin-k8s-change-interpreter-pod-configuration)? I'd really appreciate your comments...